# How to install Postgres 9.3 parallel in Debian Squeeze

Tags: postgresql, debian-squeeze, postgresql-9.3

Debian 6 contains Postgres 9.1 installation installed from Debian backports in 5432 port

How to install Postgres 9.3 also on this server.
I found instructions in http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/

Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list, and add a line for the repository

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ squeeze-pgdg main

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | \
   sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update 
apt-get install postgresql-9.3
```

Will this keep existing 9.1 installation ? In what port new installed postgres will be listen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://apt.postgresql.org/ to get releases of PostgreSQL that'll install in parallel with existing installs on Debian and Ubuntu.